# Communication between a WEB UI front-end and a C++ back-end?

Tags: c++, html, sockets, websocket

I'm creating an application that consists of a web-based front-end  and a c++ back-end and has the following requirements:
1) There should not be any installation of web server like Apache or similar software
2) The front-end UI should be able to trigger the back-end to perform specific measurements 
3) The back-end after the computation of the measurements should return the value to the front-end in order to be depicted on the WEB UI.

I'm quite new in network programming so I made a research and I found that the absence of an installed web server can be replaced by an http server implemented in c++ with a relevant library like boost or poco. 
However what confused me a lot is the way/ways that the front-end and the back-end can communicate  with each other. I'm aware that C++ is able to create not only a simple but also  a web socket.
What I'd like to ask is whether for the aforementioned functionality a simple socket will do the job or do I need to use web socket?  If a simple socket is enough to transfer the data from the back to front-end in what way the html front-end can communicate with the c++ back-end? In your opinion which is the most stable and efficient way?

Comment: The way i'm currently using is an HTTP server written in C++ with WebSockets enabled. Is the way to go. But if you don't need realtime and simple HTTP call you can achieve this with Ajax.

Comment: Websockets is a protocol name (similar to how HTTP is the name of a protocol) - not a type of a socket.

Answer (score 0):

Communication with the web browser requires the use of whatever features the web browser happens to support. A "simple socket" is not something that exists in browsers.

The majority of all web applications use simple HTTP requests (so-called "AJAX") to a "REST" interface for most interactions, and WebSockets for those that require the ability to "subscribe" to live changes or where bandwidth-efficiency is more important than resilience against disconnections.

Remember that the browser only (generally) supports JavaScript, and that your communication between front-end and back-end is transactional by default (that is, request-response as opposed to message handling.)